# Drupal Geofield - Include map along with with fields in a view

Tags: drupal-7, geolocation, drupal-views

I want to have a single proximity filter that filters both articles and markers on the map in one hit.

At the moment users have to fill in two forms to keep the map in sync with the articles. This done by two separate views because I can't include fields and a map in the same view.

How can I include a geofield map and fields in one view and have both filtered by a single exposed form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't include fields and a map in the same view.

This is not true, you can use **Views Attachments** display! So below a map you can have a group of other results such as a list, table etc with the same exposed filters, arguments etc.

Comment: Many thanks. I hope you dont think that I was putting Drupal down. I just didn't know about attachments. So not only have I solved my problem, I have just learned something new and Drupal once again becomes an even more powerful tool.